# R for loop with a multiplication by 2

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to do a loop for in R by multiplying the variable j by 2.

I use normally :

```
for (j in seq(0,10,2)){
#myloop 
}
```

But this is used to add by 2 and not multiply.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean to have a sequence of 0,2,4,8,16... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a geometric sequence

```
for (j in 2^(0:10)) {}

2^(0:10)
> [1]    1    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512 1024
```

Comment: Ah ok! I want to know how can I put a limit? For instance, I want to limit at 65. So the iteration has to stop at 64.

Comment: `2^(0:floor(log(limit, base = 2)))`